# Magento : How to Change Attribute Label For Configurable Product

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento1.9.2.3

I want to change attribute label of products. For that I have changed its label in backend like as shown in below image,

[image]

I want to change an attribute name from `Flavour` to `Flavour` Options but it still shows Flavour at frontend.

[image]

I checked further and found on product edit page, under associated products tab, it still showing Flavour and it doesn't use default value. If I use its default value then it works fine and show correct attribute name at frontend. see image--

[image]

There are hundreds of products, so I can't change them manually.

How can I use default value for all products for that store or can edit the value of attribute name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by a single database query.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` SET `use_default`= 1;
```

Run this in your database and it will use default value for all of your products attributes.

Comment: Thanks Jainam, I have already resolved it before your answering. Thanks once again

Comment: But I don't know why it is happening only with one website , while on other website it works without changing in DB.

Comment: Did you use the same method or any other method to resolve it? @shashank

Comment: Since it didn't work at admin so I did it from DB query.